# How do I use a variable from a JavaScript file to my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, dom, onclick

I am new to this and need help please. I have a variable in my javascript file that I wanted to respond to a button in my HTML file. Once the button is clicked I wanted my button to call the variable and a new message would appear.

The goal of the project is to generate a new random message once the button is clicked.

here is the javascript below

```js
const messages = [
  "Hello!",
  "How are you doing today?",
  "Have a great day!",
  "What's up?",
  "Hope you're doing well!",
  "Take care!",
  "Enjoy your day!",
  "Stay positive!",
  "Sending you good vibes!",
  "Smile and be happy!",
  "Did I do this right?",
  "I wonder",
  "Hello World",
  "Hey There",
  "Elijah is awesome",
  "arrays are powerful",
  "Javascript is really hard",
  "HTML and CSS are easy"
];

// Function to generate a random index
function getRandomIndex(array) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

// Generate a random message
function generateRandomMessage() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(messages);
  const randomMessage = messages[randomIndex];
  return randomMessage;
}


// Call the function to generate a random message

const randomMessage = generateRandomMessage();

console.log(randomMessage);


var newContent = randomMessage;
var contentHolder = document.getElementById('content-holder');

contentHolder.innerHTML = newContent;
```

```html
<p id="content-holder">
</p>
<button ondblclick="newContent">click</button>
```

I tried using the "onclick" attribute but had no success

I tried using the getElementById with no success maybe I'm not doing it right?

I tried googling it and ended up where I started...LOST

Im not sure what to try, I am just starting my coding journey and am lost. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for error messages? I also see no buttons in your HTML, just one paragraph

Comment: The code that's *not* in a function (the bit that gets the message then updates the DOM) needs to be in a function.  Then you call that function from outside the function (as you have const randomMessage = generateRandomMessage();) - then you can add your new function to the `onclick=setRandomMessage()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const messages = [
    "Hello!",
    "How are you doing today?",
    "Have a great day!",
    "What's up?",
    "Hope you're doing well!",
    "Take care!",
    "Enjoy your day!",
    "Stay positive!",
    "Sending you good vibes!",
    "Smile and be happy!",
    "Did I do this right?",
    "I wonder",
    "Hello World",
    "Hey There",
    "Elijah is awesome",
    "arrays are powerful",
    "Javascript is really hard",
    "HTML and CSS are easy"
];

// Function to generate a random index
function getRandomIndex(array) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

// Generate a random message
function generateRandomMessage() {
    const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(messages);
    const randomMessage = messages[randomIndex];
    return randomMessage;
}


// Call the function to generate a random message

function postMes (){
    const randomMessage = generateRandomMessage();


    var newContent = randomMessage;
    var contentHolder = document.getElementById('content-holder');

    contentHolder.innerHTML = newContent;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="content-holder">
</p>
<button onclick="postMes()">click</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just put the part of posting a message in a function

Comment: So the solution was to wrap it in the function postMes() and then call the function with the onclick attribute?

Comment: @JorgeMartinApresaPerez No problem, Good luck in learning programming))

Comment: @JorgeMartinApresaPerez If you want to call a piece of javascript code, you need to put that piece of code in a function and call it. You can call it in many ways, you can use onclick as in the example, or you can use [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Arsen MKrtumian I very much appriciate it. Awesome!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You only have to rearrange your code a little bit.

```js
const messages = [
  "Hello!",
  "How are you doing today?",
  "Have a great day!",
  "What's up?",
  "Hope you're doing well!",
  "Take care!",
  "Enjoy your day!",
  "Stay positive!",
  "Sending you good vibes!",
  "Smile and be happy!",
  "Did I do this right?",
  "I wonder",
  "Hello World",
  "Hey There",
  "Elijah is awesome",
  "arrays are powerful",
  "Javascript is really hard",
  "HTML and CSS are easy"
];

// Function to generate a random index
function getRandomIndex(array) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

// Generate a random message
function generateRandomMessage() {
  const randomIndex = getRandomIndex(messages);
  const randomMessage = messages[randomIndex];
  var newContent = randomMessage;
  var contentHolder = document.getElementById('content-holder');

  contentHolder.innerHTML = newContent;
}
```

```html
<p id="content-holder">
</p>
<button onclick="generateRandomMessage()">click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! So, what you did there was make the bottom part into a function to be able to call the gerneratRandomMessage() ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Additionally to shifting some parts into the generateRandomMessage() - function in the JS, I added your function to the button in the HTML, such that clicking the button (`onclick`) calls the function (`generateRandomMessage()`).

Comment: You're welcome. However, please avoid "thanks" - or similar comments. We use technical writing here. If my answer was helpful for you, you can use the upvote button.